# What is the deployment workflow if using CoffeeScript and an IDE for developing a web application?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, netbeans, coffeescript, build-automation

I've just picked up CoffeeScript and I'm struggling to understand the deployment workflow. It seems you constantly have to compile the .coffee files before using them. (Yes, I'm aware that you can have it embedded in the browser, but that's not recommended for production applications).

Does one have to constantly (manually) compile the files before deploying? (For example, if using Eclipse, a simple Ctrl+S saves and deploys the .war/.ear on the local machine's server.) Do we have to change the build scripts (for a central, possible CI server) for deploying .coffee files? Is there anyway to have integrated compiling via the IDEs (Eclipse/Netbeans)

Any ideas/pointers/examples on this? How/what have you used in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) in my Cakefile to pre-compile and package my CoffeeScript for the browser. For an example of how I call browserify as well as coffeedoc and coffeedoctest take a look at the [Cakefile for my Lumenize project](https://github.com/lmaccherone/Lumenize/blob/master/Cakefile).

If you are using express or some other node based server, you can have your CoffeeScript compiled at request time, using tools like [NibJS](https://github.com/blambeau/nib.js) or as described in [The Little Book on CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/) (Applications chapter), you can use [Stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch). BTW, I highly recommend, The Little Book. The "Compiling" chapter has information about Cake and compiling that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have a build script. Most CoffeeScript projects use a Cakefile for this; see, for example, [37signals' pow](https://github.com/37signals/pow/blob/master/Cakefile). With a Cakefile, you can just run

```
cake build
```

from the command line to run the `build` task in the Cakefile.

You can run the Cakefile on a CI server, assuming that you have Node and CoffeeScript installed on that server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't deploy the coffee files, use something like "coffee -cwj" to constantly watch and compile the .coffee files into javascript (.js) files and deploy those.

The options are c=compile, w=watch and j=join the files.

See the [coffee-script web site](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) for details of the options you can pass in.